# Is it possible to Remove EventSources and add them back dynamically based on View Name?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to set up a calendar with multiple views that are all identical except for the events displayed on each. I am able to remove EventSources by ID through the viewSkeleton Render callback - but I am unable to add an EventSource back to the calendar.

Searched extensively for ways to toggle visibility and things like that - but most results are for previous versions of FullCalendar - trying to accomplish this in v4.

Reduced Test Case:
https://codepen.io/jacobcboe/pen/MReJep

I'm actually trying to do this with Google Calendar EventSources, but used array events for test case for simplicity.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'timeGrid' ],
    views: {
     view1: {
   type: 'timeGrid',
   duration: { days:7 },
   buttonText: 'view1'
  },
  view2: {
   type: 'timeGrid',
   duration: { days:7 },
   buttonText: 'view2'
  },
  view3: {
      type: 'timeGrid',
   duration: { days:7 },
   buttonText: 'view3'
  },
  view4: {
   type: 'timeGrid',
   duration: { days:7 },
   buttonText: 'view4'
  }   
 },
    defaultView: 'view1',
    defaultDate: '2019-04-05',
    header: {
      left: 'view1,view2,view3,view4',
      center: '',
      right: ''
    },
    eventSources: [
      {
        id:'1',
        events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2019-04-05'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2019-04-06',
          end: '2019-04-07'
        }]
      },
      {
        id:'2',
        events:[
          {
            groupId: '999',
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-04-05T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            groupId: '999',
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-04-06T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2019-04-05',
            end: '2019-04-10'
          }]
      },
      {
        id:'3',
        events: [
          {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2019-04-09T10:30:00',
        end: '2019-04-09T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2019-04-08T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2019-04-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2019-04-07T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2019-04-11'
      }]
      }
    ],
    viewSkeletonRender: function(info) {
      var eventSourceOne = calendar.getEventSourceById('1');
      eventSourceOne.remove();
      var eventSourceTwo = calendar.getEventSourceById('2');
      eventSourceTwo.remove();
      var eventSourceThree = calendar.getEventSourceById('3');
      eventSourceThree.remove();
      //also tried calendar.getEvents() with remove
      var viewName = info.view
      if(viewName.type =='view1'){
        calendar.addEventSource(eventSourceOne);
        //have also tried eventSourceOne.refetch()
      }
      if(viewName.type =='view2'){
        calendar.addEventSource(eventSourceTwo);
      }
      if(viewName.type =='view3'){
        calendar.addEventSource(eventSourceThree);
      }
      if(viewName.type =='view4'){
        calendar.addEventSource(eventSourceOne);
        calendar.addEventSource(eventSourceTwo);
        calendar.addEventSource(eventSourceThree);
      }
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timegrid/4.0.1/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/daygrid/4.0.1/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.0.2/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.0.2/main.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timegrid/4.0.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/daygrid/4.0.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.0.2/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to show different events for each view? The idea of views is simply to give different ways of presenting the same information. What's the use case for this? fullCalendar isn't really designed for what you're describing, although I guess it might be possible. But first I'm interested in why it's necessary

Comment: I'm attempting to make a family calendar with filtered views for each family member (all events shown by default, but with a button to show only events from one persons calendar). Obviously this can be done in google calendar, but this is emebedded on a website with other information to be displayed in the house - so it has to look better than google calendar - hence fullcalendar.

Comment: Ok but none of that requires you to use viewskeletonrender as far as I can see. If the user changes from "month" to "week" view, for instance, you don't have to reload the events. It's just a different way of displaying the same ones.

Comment: If you have a list of family members, it sounds like what you probably want is to display the list by the side of the calendar, and make them clickable. Clicking on each one would run an event in which you add/remove that person's events from the calendar (by adding / removing the event source associated with that person)

Comment: Yes - I certainly don't need to use Views to accomplish this, it just seemed an easy way to get buttons at the top of the calendar. I didn't think it would matter what triggered the code - but I will try this with buttons to add/remove event sources and see if that works.

Comment: I created a Fork on the codepen (https://codepen.io/jacobcboe/pen/GLxBKM) and removed the Views and instead used custom buttons. I am able to remove all events from the calendar on a button click, but I am not able to re-add a specific Event Source after that. I've tried both calendar.getEventSources -> eventSources.remove() as well as calendar.getEvents -> iterate over array and remove each - both will remove events, but events fail to get added back after. Any recommendation on how to get events to be added back to calendar after removal?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do there...you remove some events individually, and then you get an existing event source (which by now probably has no events in it, since you deleted them) and try to add it to the calendar again (without removing the event source itself).

Comment: I think you need to remove the relevant event source each time, not individual events. And then add back in the other event source, if it's been removed previously.

Comment: Here, try this version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOdvZv . Notice how a) I store the event sources separately in an array so you can get them back after you've removed them from the calendar, and b) I only add and remove sources, never individual events.

Comment: P.S. The custom buttons idea is interesting but won't scale very well if you need several of them. You'll need a better way of mapping which event sources belong to which button than just hard-coding it.